# How to convert JSON object into an array in React Native

Tags: arrays, json, react-native

I am getting a JSON object from Firebase. I am trying to convert it into an array of objects.

I can solve this by getting childs from Firebase one-by-one and add them into array however, that is not a good practice for my case.

The format of JSON object is as following:

```
key: {
      id1: {some stuff here},
      id2: {some other stuff},
    ...
}
```

Now what I want to get from this JSON object is :

```
arrayName: [
         {id1:{some stuff here},
         id2:{some other stuff}
]
```

Hope my description if fully understandable.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just plain javascript, it has nothing to do with react native. By the way, you can use `Object.keys` to get an array with all the keys, then map the strings as objects:

```js
const x = {foo: 11, bar: 42};
const result = Object.keys(x).map(key => ({[key]: x[key]}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am new to Javacript, just trying to learn through React Native.

Comment: Let me give you an advice, just don't start with React Native. That's an advanced topic, it solves some problems that you aren't aware of

Answer (score 7):

This code worked for me.

```
const JSONString = res.data;
      object = JSON.parse(JSONString);
      array = Object.keys(object).map(function(k) {
        return object[k];
      });
```

Where res.data is the response I am getting from an api

Comment: The above code given by Cristian Traina worked fine. I will use that

Comment: Thank you so much, brother! Your answer work for me.
I am getting response like "[{"id":1,"title":"\u30aa\u30b9"},{"id":2,"title":"\u30e1\u30b9"},{"id":3,"title":"\u30aa\u30b9\/\u53bb\u52e2\u6e08"},{"id":4,"title":"\u30e1\u30b9\/\u907f\u598a\u6e08"},{"id":5,"title":"\u4ed6"}]"
And your answer gave me perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), you can avoid the extra hash lookup on every item.

```js
const x = { foo: 11, bar: 42 };
const result = Object.entries(x).map(([key, val]) => ({
  [key]: val
}));
console.log(result);
```